Perl CGI Fails with Permission Denied - AH01241: Error spawning CGI child
I have a Perl CGI script Test.cgi at /var/www/cgi-bin/Test.cgi. The content is simply:
#!/bin/perl -T
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Hello, World.";

The issue is that when I try to access this script via Web browser I get a 500 Internal Server Error, and /var/log/httpd/error_log has
AH01241: error spawning CGI child: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/Test.cgi' failed (Permission denied): /var/www/cgi-bin/Test.cgi

I. Permissions:
Below the permissions for the /var/www/cgi-bin folder and the Test.cgi script (including SELinux types)
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0        86 Jul 10 16:37 cgi-bin
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0    72 Jul 10 17:22 Test.cgi

II. httpd.conf:
User apache
Group apache

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Require all granted
</Directory>

So far I've tried...

Disabling SELinux with $ setenforce 0 and reloading the browser. No luck.

Lastly...
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Server built:   Feb 16 2024 04:23:20

# uname -a
Linux linux 4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 14 14:20:09 EDT 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# perl -v
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

What am I missing here?
UPDATE:
Thanks to @larsks I now know the issue with the Permission denied when calling from the terminal was due to a noexec mount option in the /var filesystem. That was fixed and now I can run the script from the terminal. The original issue persists, though. Still see the same Permission denied error on the /var/log/httpd/error_log when accessing the CGI from the browser.

The solution was to completely disable SELinux. I verified that in Permissive mode in simply would not work.
To disable SELinux set SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config

Yes, that can work, but I strongly discourage it.
Instead of disabling SELinux, you can diagnose and fix the specific issues using SELinux troubleshooting tools. Commands like audit2allow and sealert can help identify and address the problems while keeping SELinux enabled for better security. I have added more to my answer, including a script that saves a lot of time.

I agree Max, but at least I could finally pinpoint the issue. Now it's a matter of refinement, and the script you shared will be very useful to that end. Thank you again.

Make sure that the path to Perl in the shebang line is correct. Typically, it's #!/usr/bin/perl -T
Use the command which perl to determine the Perl installation you are using by default.
Verify that /var/www/cgi-bin and its parent directories are accessible by the Apache user.
Use ls -ld /var/www/cgi-bin and ls -ld /var/www to check permissions.
Setting setenforce 0 to disable SELinux temporarily should be effective and equivalent to setting permissive mode in the configuration and rebooting.
If setenforce 0 doesn't work, it suggests that the issue might not be related to SELinux.
Confirm that the file system where /var/www/cgi-bin is located does not have the noexec option set.
mount | grep ' /var'

Remount it without noexec if necessary.
Double-check your Apache configuration to ensure it allows CGI execution. There was a redundant "Options None".
User apache
Group apache

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

# ScriptAlias for CGI directory
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Also, make sure the Apache user has a valid shell in /etc/passwd.
The Apache user should have something like /sbin/nologin. If it is set to /bin/false, change it to /sbin/nologin.
To make sure PERL scripts can run, create a simple CGI script to print the environment variables, like this:
Create /var/www/cgi-bin/Test.cgi
sudo vim /var/www/cgi-bin/Test.cgi

Then add this content to it
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
foreach $key (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
    print "$key = $ENV{$key}<br>\n";
}

Use :wq to write the file and quit.
Make sure the SELinux context is correctly set. You can try resetting the context:
restorecon -v /var/www/cgi-bin/Test.cgi

Check if apache can read and execute the script:
sudo -u apache /var/www/cgi-bin/Test.cgi

The script shall run without errors.  This can help diagnose if there are any missing or problematic environment variables.
Using a web browser, I'd guess you'd find it at:
http://yourdomain/cgi-bin/Test.cgi

** Delete Test.cgi when no longer needed!**
Restart Apache after making any configuration changes using systemctl restart httpd.
Check the audit logs for detailed information on why permission was denied:
sudo ausearch -m avc -ts recent

If you've tried all that and are still encountering issues, please share any new error messages or logs that might provide additional context for further troubleshooting, please add them in the comments, then we'd have an idea of where to look next.
If you're still having issues with SELinux, here is a generic script that can help you prevent lowering your guard:
It installs necessary packages: policycoreutils-python-utils and setroubleshoot-server.
Sets SELinux to permissive mode: This logs policy violations without enforcing them.
Generates and applies an SELinux policy module: This allows actions previously blocked.
Analyzes SELinux denials: Saves detailed analysis to selinux_analysis.txt.
Reviews recent SELinux denials: Saves recent denials to recent_denials.txt.
#!/bin/bash

# if the user is root
if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Please run this script as root or with sudo."
  exit 1
fi

#  install necessary packages
install_packages() {
  echo "Installing necessary packages..."
  yum install -y policycoreutils-python-utils setroubleshoot-server
}

# set SELinux to permissive mode
set_permissive() {
  echo "Setting SELinux to permissive mode..."
  setenforce 0
  if [ "$(getenforce)" != "Permissive" ]; then
    echo "Failed to set SELinux to permissive mode."
    exit 1
  fi
}

# generate and apply SELinux policy module
generate_policy_module() {
  echo "Generating SELinux policy module..."
  ausearch -c 'httpd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-httpd
  if [ -f my-httpd.pp ]; then
    echo "Applying SELinux policy module..."
    semodule -i my-httpd.pp
  else
    echo "Failed to generate SELinux policy module."
    exit 1
  fi
}

# analyze SELinux denials
analyze_denials() {
  echo "Analyzing SELinux denials..."
  sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log > selinux_analysis.txt
  echo "SELinux analysis saved to selinux_analysis.txt"
}

# review recent SELinux denials
review_denials() {
  echo "Reviewing recent SELinux denials..."
  ausearch -m avc -ts recent > recent_denials.txt
  echo "Recent SELinux denials saved to recent_denials.txt"
}

# Main
main() {
  install_packages
  set_permissive
  generate_policy_module
  analyze_denials
  review_denials
  echo "SELinux troubleshooting steps completed."
}

# Run the main function
main

Save it an make it executable:
chmod +x selinux_troubleshoot.sh

Run the script as root:
sudo ./selinux_troubleshoot.sh

This script automates the steps needed to diagnose and address SELinux issues without completely disabling SELinux. It ensures your system remains secure while troubleshooting specific issues.
Good luck!

Thank you Max. I'll run all these and update the question/comments.

I tried these solutions to no avail, and I've updated the question. What else can we try?

@MaxHaase, do you have any reason to believe that setenforce 0 would not be effective (compared to setting permissive mode in the configuration and rebooting)? That would seem to be a major bug if true, and it's certainly not anything I've ever encountered.

I tried to improve my answer, including the SELinux part. Are you sure the user is apache and not www-data? Make sure the correct user is executing the script. I'm guessing here, but make sure that also applies to all the related scripts that spawn during the execution.
Execute the script that dumps all the environment variables to the screen. (delete the script when no longer needed). That should give you a good hint of a common issue. It is meant to be executed from the web browser through Apache, notice the -T is in the script, that doesn't run like that from the command line.

@larsks I had to make sure my statement is correct, because to me it also had the impression of being a bug. But after an exhaustive investigation, I reached the conclusion that the statement is correct. I have updated the answer with a link to the explanation because it is rather long.

So SELinux was involved after all. Thank you both.
